# Search and extract value in array by pattern

Tags: javascript

I've got following code:

```
var inputData = 'email@gmail.com';
var email = inputData.match(/^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+$/);
```

While it seems to work fine and its return value if the pattern is matched, I've faced with the issue when I change `inputData` to array type like:

```
var inputData = [1, 'text', 'email@gmail.com']
```

When input data is like that, it says `inputData.match` is not a function". How to fix this? I'm quite new to JS so any help would be appreciated. Ideally, I want if pattern requirements were met it should return only first email in var email.

Comment: `inputData[2].match(/^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+$/);`

Comment: but it can be in any random place, getting by array number won't work either

Comment: inputData.find(item => \`${item}\`.match(/^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+$/))

Comment: @RedEclipse there is no code that can handle **all** the scenarios. What if it's the email is a nested object? Don't you know what is the format your app working with?!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `find` method of the array to find the first item that matches. You will have to convert each item to a string first, because numbers don't have a match method.

`` inputData.find(item => `${item}`.match(/^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+$/)) ``

Comment: it still throws same error. What if input data would be an object?

Comment: Depends - what do you want to do in that situation? Not test it or test some part of it?

Answer (score 0):

```
var inputData = [1, 'text', 'email@gmail.com']

var emails = [];
var i;
for (var i=0 ; i < inputData.length ; i++)
{
        emails.push(inputData[i].match(/^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+$/));

}
console.log(emails);
```

Did it in this way